# Web site for overlaying graph of exchange rate (e.g. USD/EUR) on S&P 500 index chart? 

Tags: investing, currency, online-tools, market-indexes, chart

I would like to overlay the US Dollar exchange-rate vs the Euro with the S&P 500. What is the simplest way to do that? Is there a website that does that type of thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be what you seek.

[Yahoo Euro vs S&P](http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=eurusd=x#chart2:symbol=%5Edji;range=1y;compare=eurusd=x;indicator=volume;charttype=line;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=on;source=undefined)

the link shows:

[image: comparison chart]

Comment: Im getting this error: Oops!
 No data available for 5egspc - it just shows the Dow graph.

Comment: I used the compare option and put in: CCY: EURUSD=X and that worked. \thankyou  perhapse the problem is something like the following: only half the link is activated: http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=eurusd=x#chart2:symbol=^dji;range=1y;compare=eurusd=x;indicator=volume;charttype=line;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=on;source=undefined

Comment: I think I fixed the link so it works now instead of the "5egspc" error.

Comment: Indeed you did =)

Comment: Thanks Alex. Link worked for me, but if it didn't work on some browsers, I guess you cleaned it up. Nice work.